# Получение ссылки из адреса страницы

Tags: html

Если пользователь находится на странице https://www.site.com/one/index.html, как на этой странице вывести ссылку с другим доменом в виде https://en.site.com/one/index.html?

То есть, чтобы в тексте страницы прописалась ссылка на английскую версию текущей страницы.

Ссылку нужно сгенерировать автоматически, на основе адреса страницы. Таких страниц много, вручную прописывать долго.

Спасибо!

Comment: так напишите нужную ссылку. в чём проблема? лучше не отвечать на комментарий, а внести уточнения в текст вопроса, нажав [edit]

Comment: Вы хотите добавить ссылку на странице, или изменить адрес в адресной строке?

Comment: Ссылку нужно сгенерировать автоматически, на основе адреса страницы. Таких страниц много, прописывать долго. Нужно именно ссылку прописать.

Comment: Используйте `window.location`, на основе `window.location.href`, `window.location.host` и `window.location.pathname` можете составить необходимый Вам адрес который потом можно подставить в `href` атрибут нужного Вам элемента.

Comment: 2Simon А можно код, пожалуйста? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так:

```js
const enLink = document.getElementById('enLink'); // получаем елемент
const currentHref = window.location.href; // получаем адрес страницы
const newHref = currentHref.replace('stacksnippets.net', 'example.com'); // выполняем необходимую подмену в адресе
enLink.href = newHref; // подставляем в ссылку
```

```html
<a id='enLink'>English</a>
```

Или одной строкой:

```js
document.getElementById('enLink').href = window.location.href.replace('stacksnippets.net', 'example.com');
```

```html
<a id='enLink'>English</a>
```

> А если мне не нужно один сайт на другой менять, а "www" заменить на "en", что нужно в коде прописать? (site.com/one/index.html -> en.site.com/one/index.html)
> "В лоб" вот так, а вообще можно поиграться и сделать красивее:

```js
const enLink = document.getElementById('enLink'); // получаем елемент
const currentHref = 'https://site.com/one/index.html' //window.location.href; // подставляю адрес для наглядности
const newHref = currentHref.replace(/http(s)?:\/\/(www\.)?site.com/, 'https://en.site.com'); // выполняем необходимую подмену в адресе
enLink.href = newHref; // подставляем в ссылку
```

```html
<a id='enLink'>English</a>
```

Comment: another_login Я прошу прощения, код

const enLink = document.getElementById('enLink'); // получаем елемент
const currentHref = window.location.href; // получаем адрес страницы
const newHref = currentHref.replace('stacksnippets.net', 'example.com'); // выполняем необходимую подмену в адресе
enLink.href = newHref; // подставляем в ссылку

между какими тегами заключать? :)

Comment: Либо как внешний файл, либо внутри `<script type="text/javascript">...</script>`.

Comment: Спасибо! А если мне не нужно один сайт на другой менять, а "www" заменить на "en", что нужно в коде прописать? (https://www.site.com/one/index.html -> https://en.site.com/one/index.html)

Comment: @Александр, добавил.

Comment: Спасибо большое!